# adding callback to plugin, after plugin initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote a simple jQuery plugin. 
my plugin create a HTML element with 'forward' button.
The button do some stuff, and can call a callback, if user set one.

I can add a callback in initialization stage like(option 1):

```
$('selector').myPlugin({onForward: function(){console.log('forward'); } });
```

And that's work fine.

But when I try to set a callback after the plugin created(option 2):

```
var $plugin = $('selector').myPlugin();
$plugin.myPlugin('onForward',function(){console.log('forward'); });
```

The plugin is not triggering the callback.

I have a 'defaults' variable which i use for saving the callback.

```
var defaults = {
 onForward:         function (){}, // initialize with empty callback
}
```

When I set it with "onForward" method, using debugger, I can see the value of defaults.onForward is set with the new callback, but when the button is triggered, it seems
like the button 'forgot' the method i set earlier and use the default empty method which was in initialization.

Here is a snip of the plugin code:

```
    (function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(methodOrOptions){

        var $self = $(this);
        var defaults = {
                onForward:      function (){},
        };
        var methods = {
                init: function(options){
                    $.extend(defaults,options);
                    $self.find('button#forward').on('click',events.forward); 
                    return $self;
                },
                onForward: function(callback){
                    defaults.onForward      = callback; // setting the callback after initialization
                },

        };
        var events = {
                forward: function(){
                    // do stuff and call the callback
                    defaults.onForward();
                }
        }
        if(methods[methodOrOptions]){
            return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        }
        else if(typeof(methodOrOptions) === 'object' || !methodOrOptions ){
            return methods.init.apply(this,arguments)
        }
        else{
            console.log('error: method: '+methodOrOptions+' does not exists');
        }

})(jQuery);
```

What am i doing wrong ??
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that every time you call the `myPlugin()` function you actually get a new instance of `defaults`. So the instance you are modifying in the first call is actually a different instance than the one you are modifying in the second call.

To circumvent this you have to store the defaults in the `data()` object of your component and then call it in a new unit of time for each function call:

```
$self.data("defaults", defaults)
```

And the to get it again in the on forward method, you have to do something like this:

```
onForward: function(callback){
   var $self = $(this);                    
   $self.data("defaults").onForward = callback; 
}
```

And your event handler should look somewhat like this:

```
 var events = {
     forward: function(){
        $self.data("defaults").onForward();
     }
 }
```

See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s4rjh9a4/1/